# Does collecting coins in Plants vs. Zombies play a song or just random notes?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Playing in my Zen garden I sometimes collect 20-30 coins, and they tend to make very melodic tunes. Do the coins play the notes of a particular song or is a random note played each time? I've tried collecting them with different beats to reveal a song with no luck, maybe someone with a larger zen garden can figure it out?

Comment: As a joke, I thought about saying it plays [Zombie on Your Lawn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0N1_0SUGlDQ), which is an official Plants vs. Zombies song.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I emailed Popcap to ask, and they said the following:

> There is no music to the coins, they are just all random notes.  So if you are hearing music, that's pretty cool and means you have a good imagination or ear for melody.

Comment: Noticing a pattern in random noise (not just auditorily) is called apophenia or pareidolia.

Answer (score 6):

I played the game to death, unlocking every single thing in it and I also tried to find a pattern to picking the coins up. From what I could tell, they're just different notes that link well together.